# Constructing gauge invariants

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, representation-theory

Is there an efficient way for constructing gauge invariants given the number of operators one can use is fixed. For example, if I am given some  boson in $\mathbf{3}$ of $SU(2)$, and I want to find out the number of possible invariants constructed when I have 20 such objects. One can construct an object like
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}_{a_1,b_1}...\mathcal{O}_{a_{20},b_{20}}\epsilon^{a1,a3}....\epsilon^{a6,b3}
\end{equation}
I want to find out how many such objects are possible.
Is there an efficient way of doing such things for other representations like $\mathbf{5}$, $\mathbf{6}$,..etc, for fermions or maybe mixed objects like $\mathbf{4}$ and $\mathbf{7}$. I was trying to use mathematica for contractions but the number of partitions grows very fast and doing it brute force doesn't seem to be an option. Any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: Isn't it the multiplicity of the identity rep in the tensor product of all the reps? Maybe need to do some symmetrization/anti-symmetrization if they are all identical particles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [this reference](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physleta.2016.12.006),
*Spin Multiplicities*,  T Curtright, T van Kortryk,  and C Zachos, *Phys Lett* **A381** (2017) 422-427.

The character of a spin *j*, dimension 2*j*+1 irrep of SU(2) is
$$
\chi_j (\theta)= \frac{\sin((2j+1)\theta/2)}{\sin (\theta/2)}, \tag{4}
$$
and the multiplicity of spin *s* in their *n*-fold composition is
$$
M(s;n;j)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \!\! d\vartheta ~\sin^2{\vartheta} ~~ (\chi_j(2\vartheta))^n ~\chi_s(2\vartheta), \tag{5}
$$
whence, in your case,
$$
M(0;20;1)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \!\! d\vartheta ~\sin^2{\vartheta} ~~ (\chi_1(2\vartheta))^{20} ,
$$
the hypergeometric function of (17). Since this *n* is large, this is quite close to
$$
{ 3^{20.5} \over 8\sqrt{\pi} ~ 20^{3/2} },
$$
by (31). Millions...

The method addresses your further questions. Try a few simple examples, to ensure you understand the language.

Comment: Thanks, it would have been useful if I could get the index structure as well. I need all the singlets, this method gives me the multiplicity only. But, thanks a lot !!

Comment: It is a non-random walk... steps to the right, standing in place, and steps to the left, starting at the origin. Might look at small *n* s ... 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...